# How to connect and verify domain to Firebase?

Tags: firebase, dns

I am trying to connect my GoDaddy domain to Firebase:

[image]

These records that Firebase saying to remove are already not there in my records, it's a new domain
and in the above alert, it is saying `not found`.

What can I do to resolve this issue?